# Range of Feasible Values of a Variable in Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix that satisfies certain conditions and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Consider the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax \leq b$.

For a component $x_i$ of $x$, I want to prove certain property on the range $[m_i, M_i]$ of the values $x_i$ can take. More specifically, I want to show $M_i - m_i \leq c$ for some constant $c$.

One way to do this is consider two linear programmes over the above feasible set with objective functions $\max x_i$ and $\min x_i$. However, this turns out to be quite difficult to analyse theoretically.

I wonder if anyone has encountered any paper in the literature where people have tried to prove a similar statement. I've done some search but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could analyze
$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\max_{x,y} & y_i-x_i \\
s.t. & Ax \leq b \text{ and } Ay \leq b
\end{array}
$$
It seems easier to analyze.

Comment: I had a similar thought.  Now to derive an upper bound $y_i-x_i \le c$, exhibit a dual feasible solution with dual objective value $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and comment. Inadvertently, I've tried doing something similar when I analysed the two linear programmes with objective functions $\max x_i$ and $\min x_i$. In other words, I found a dual objective value $a$ for the programme with $\min x_i$, and have tried to bound the objective of the programme with $\max x_i$ by $c + a$.